# Does the YouTube Data API expose multi-camera livestream functionality?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to integrate a YouTube live event which uses [multi-camera views as per Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853812?hl=en) into a site - I'd love to be able to access both camera views from the live event if possible.

Does the YouTube Data API support querying the multiple different camera views? Are they listed as children of a single event? What's the returned data structure like?

Or is this simply not possible - i.e. a single live event with multiple cameras will show in the API as just a standard live event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YouTube Live Streaming API does not support multiple camera angles at this time.  The [API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started#resources) specify that a `liveEvent` can only be bound to one `liveStream`

> `liveStream` - Contains information about the video stream that you are transmitting to YouTube. The stream provides the content that will be broadcast to YouTube users. Once created, a liveStream resource can be bound to exactly one liveBroadcast resource. (Similarly, the liveBroadcast resource can only be bound to one liveStream resource.