# How to create and event with multiple cams with youtube-livestreaming-api

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to use youtube-livestream-api to create an Event and adding cameras.

What I have tried so far is:

1) Create single Broadcast with broadCasts.insert and then bind multiple streams. That didn't work, as I found out in the documentation.

2) Create multiple broadCasts and bind it to every stream, but when I go to the Youtube Content Editor, I see an event for each broadcast. Which is coherent with the documentation about a broadcast = a video.

My question is, is there any way using the API to create a single event with multiple cams, as you do in the Content Creator?

Comment: Finally i've found a similar question to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574316/does-the-youtube-data-api-expose-multi-camera-livestream-functionality?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i've found a similar question to this [Does the YouTube Data API expose multi-camera livestream functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574316/does-the-youtube-data-api-expose-multi-camera-livestream-functionality?rq=1)

In short, as is for now, there is no way with youtube API for having multiple cameras per stream.